# Salesforce Apex Web-service : How to handle different Data hierarchy between systems

Tags: apex, soap-api, integration, apexrest

Looking for some basic questions that any integration specialist must already be taking care. Please go through it and revert.Hoping to understand the approach  from the Salesforce Perspective. ----Thanks in advnace

1 Before developing an interface,from the designers point what are the tasks that he has to consider for a smooth integration. To be specific from the below terms ---

----  if two systems support different Hierarchy of data, then how designers across these systems decide,weather to go with SF structure or with X_ternal system structure.

----If at all there is any data hierarchy change,when moving data from salesforce to other system then  we consider any Middleware software for makeing any data hierarchy  conversion ?..or anything which we have to do it first }

2 If we have a custom Response to be sent  or consumed(from SF) in some other hierachy of data that our  salesforce  doesnot support then

--- How do we handle this mapping from SF to X-ternal system

---To handle this believe we need to write  some code, is there any pre-built functions available to handle the traversing of the XML data and arranging the structures as required??

Comment: You might want to split this into more than a single question.  You have a lot going on here and there is too much to answer.  Try moving those questions into individual questions and be more specific with them.    For testing REST clients: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: Chrome extension - Advanced REST client. This is good for testing REST Callouts.

Comment: THanks for the Suggestions.@dphil :Will move these questions into individual ones :)  But in here, for point 1 and point 2 which are the main ones and also related..Can I get some inputs or some references to know.

Comment: Edited my Question...Keeping only point 1 and 2 as both to me looks related. And is possible to know kind of scenarios that we come across at a very high level.